# R lists - First item always surrounded by `these`? Why? How to prevent?

Tags: r, list, api

I'm trying to make my program speak with an API, and I think these `` are preventing it. Here is an example of what is going on:

```
BODY <- list(first = "item1","second" = "item2","third" = "item3")
BODY
```

The output is:

```
$`first`
[1] "item1"

$second
[1] "item2"

$third
[1] "item3"
```

Why is `first` surrounded by these `? I think it is causing the API to not accept my JSON.

Comment: Are you using `windows`?  I tested in `mac` and it is not an issue,  I think there is a similar question sometime back regarding this issue

Comment: Hmm. when you do this: ` BODY["second"]` it also shows second as having those tick marks. Weird

Comment: Thank for reference to answer. Yes Windows.